# Wide partitions and large number of partitions in Cassandra

Tags: database-design, cassandra, data

0

We are currently facing wide Partitions for certain customers. We have data in Gbs for those partitions. We tried data modelling and partitions always seems to be skewed. We were trying to use bucketing logic to minimise the partition size. Either large number of partitions are generated for low resource consuming users or Wide partitions are generated for high resource consumers. Large number of partitions lead to heap memory bloat while wide partitions lead to slower reads.

How can i solve a situation like this ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your PRIMARY KEY definition as well as the write throughput experienced by the table?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! A friendly note to let you know that there isn't enough detail in your question so you're unlikely to get an answer. You should provide a sample schema to illustrate your issue and a minimal sample dataset for your schema would assist in understanding why you end up with wide or large partitions. Cheers!